# vba range backward from a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a value, `MyValue`, in a column and want to loop through previous `n` rows. The function, Calc, has 2  parameters: `Calc(MyValue, n)`. It roughly looks like:{Unfortunately, the Debug.Print about the row and column is empty. Hi displays.}

```
Function Calc (MyValue, n)
    Dim Copyrange As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim MyCol, MyRow, Startrow, Lastrow
    Debug.Print "Hi"
    Range(Valuex).Select
    MyCol = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(1)
    MyRow = Split(Selection.Address, "$")(2)
    Debug.Print "Row is : " & MyRow
    Debug.Print "Col is : " & MyCol
    Startrow = MyRow - n + 1
    Lastrow = MyRow
    Let Copyrange = MyCol & Startrow & ":" & MyCol & Lastrow
    Range(Copyrange).Select
    Set rng = Application.Selection
    ….xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Some loop with rng
    Calc = xxxxxxxxx
End Function
```

Comment: use `Option Explicit` as the first line of you module, and compile. Not defining your variables is a sure way to mess up your code. What is `Valuex` ???

Comment: Can you show us an example line of `Selection.Address`?

Comment: Please, *DO NOT* ignore @iDevlop's reccommendation. You will regret it, sooner than later. Do it know, and get used to it.

Comment: I suppose `MyValue` is a `Range`, and not a *value* ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your code, but I'd write it like this:

```
Function Sample(rngStart As Range, nbRows As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To rngStart
        With rngStart.Offset(-i, 0)
            Debug.Print .Address, .Value
        End With
    Next i
End Function
```